# How to get url of the form page after action?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, action

i want to get the form url after the page has been submitted to the action page.

seems like its possible in serverside : [Java seeking referer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608357/java-seeking-referer)

but is it possible in client side javascript?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.referrer` gives you the referring url in javascript.

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/GNmNQ/